# Exceptions for the whole class

Tags: python, class, exception, global

I'm writing a program in Python, and nearly every method im my class is written like this:

```
def someMethod(self):
    try:
       #...
    except someException:
       #in case of exception, do something here

       #e.g display a dialog box to inform the user 
       #that he has done something wrong
```

As the class grows, it is a little bit annoying to write the same try-except block over and over. Is it possible to create some sort of 'global' exception for the whole class? What's the recommended way in Python to deal with this?

Comment: Do you need to actually catch the exception in every method? You could not catch them in your class methods but catch them in the code that calls the methods..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write one or more exception handler functions that, given a function and the exception raised in it, does what you want to do (e.g. displays an alert).  If you need more than one, write them.

```
def message(func, e):
    print "Exception", type(e).__name__, "in", func.__name__
    print str(e)
```

Now write a decorator that applies a given handler to a called function:

```
import functools

def handle_with(handler, *exceptions):
    try:
        handler, cleanup = handler
    except TypeError:
        cleanup = lambda f, e: None
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except exceptions or Exception as e:
                return handler(func, e)
            else:
                e = None
            finally:
                cleanup(func, e)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This only captures the exceptions you specify.  If you don't specify any, `Exception` is caught. Additionally, the first argument can be a tuple (or other sequence) of two handler functions; the second handler, if given, is called in a `finally` clause. The value returned from the primary handler is returned as the value of the function call.

Now, given the above, you can write:

```
@handle_with(message, TypeError, ValueError)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

You could also do this with a context manager:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager 

@contextmanager
def handler(handler, *exceptions):
    try:
        handler, cleanup = handler
    except TypeError:
        cleanup = lambda e: None
    try:
        yield
    except exceptions or Exception as e:
        handler(e)
    else:
        e = None
    finally:
        cleanup(e)
```

Now you can write:

```
def message(e):
    print "Exception", type(e).__name__
    print str(e)

 def add(x, y):
     with handler(message, TypeError, ValueError):
         return x + y
```

Note that the context manager doesn't know what function it's in (you can find this out, sorta, using `inspect`, though this is "magic" so I didn't do it) so it gives you a little less useful information. Also, the context manager doesn't give you the opportunity to return anything in your handler.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. If one needs to handle also coroutine exceptions, she can combine this answer with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169998/how-to-create-a-python-decorator-that-can-wrap-either-coroutine-or-function

Comment: Getting error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment` at `cleanup(func, e)` if there are no exceptions

Comment: added `else` clause to set `e` to `None` in case of no exception

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two options:

1. Write a decorator that can wrap each method in the `try` block.
2. Write a "dispatcher" method that calls the appropriate method inside a `try` block, then call that method instead of the individual ones.  That is, instead of calling `obj.someMethod()`, `obj.otherMethod`, you call `obj.dispatch('someMethod')` or `obj.dispatch('otherMethod')`, where `dispatch` is a wrapper that contains the `try` block.

Your approach seems like a bit of a strange design, though.  It might make more sense to have the dialog-box stuff in some other part of the code, some higher-level event loop that catches errors and displays messages about them.