# python custom exception handler for a class

Tags: python, exception

I want to build my application with a redis cache. but maybe redis is not available all the time in our case,
so I hope, it redis works well, we use it.  if it can't work, just logging and ignore it this time.

for example:

```
try:
  conn.sadd('s', *array)
except :
  ...
```

since there are many place I will run some conn.{rediscommand},  I don't like to use try/except every place.

so the solution maybe :

```
class softcache(redis.StrictRedis):
   def sadd(key, *p):
       try:
          super(redis.StrictRedis, self).sadd(key, p)
       except:
          ..
```

but since redis have many commands,  I have to warp them one by one.

is it possible to custom a exception handler for a class to handle all the exceptions which come from this class ?

Comment: take a look at [Exceptions for the whole class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19232373/1798187). you may use decorator or dispatcher as suggested.

Comment: The syntax is `try: ... except: ...`

Comment: That's what [context managers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) are for.

Comment: @Bakuriu the problem with context manager is that you have to write a `with` block each time you do a function call. I think a wrapper/proxy would be more useful (within the mistake of catching everything...)

Comment: @ikaros45 I don't think it is a problem. If the function is defined in a library you do **not** want to modify it just to avoid typing a `with`. If someone else reads your code he wont understand what the hell is happening. *If* the function is defined by you, surely using a decorator to add exception handling might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silencing per default all exceptions is probably the worst thing you can do.

Anyway, for your problem you can write a generic wrapper that just redirects to the connection object.

```
class ReddisWrapper(object):

    conn = conn # Here your reddis object

    def __getattr__(self, attr):

         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
             # Get the real reddis function
             fn = getattr(self.conn, attr)

             # Execute the function catching exceptions
             try:
                  return fn(*args, **kwargs)

             # Specify here the exceptions you expect                 
             except:
                  log(...)

         return wrapper
```

And then you would call like this:

```
reddis = ReddisWrapper()
reddis.do_something(4)
```

This has not been tested, and will only work with methods. For properties you should catch the non callable exception and react properly.

Comment: hi ikaros45,   your suggestion is easiest understand by me.  but seems not works. ` class X(object):
    def p(self, a): 
        print(a)
        raise '1' 


class WX(object):
    x = X() 

    def __getattr__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        print args
        fn = getattr(self.x, item)
        print("fn", fn) 
        try:
            fn(args)
        except:
            print("get Exception")

wx = WX()
wx.p('abc')
print "ok" `

Comment: hi ikaros45,  thanks for suggestion.  it works now with the following code.      def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self.__conn, attr):
            def wapper(*args, **kw):
                fn = getattr(self.__conn, attr)
                try:
                    return fn(*args, **kw)
                except redis.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                    pass
            return wapper
        raise AttributeError()

Comment: can you modify your answer so that I can accept your answer.  I learnt much from your suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: @zhihuifan, I'm happy to help but I don't understand the code you posted in the comments.

Comment: if you try your suggestion,  you will found __getattr__ only accept 2 arguments, not 4.   in my comment, __getattr__ return a pointer to function wapper,  wapper accept these parameters, that works.

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer to work with a closure as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the same `Exception`?

If so you could write a custom, Exception catching and logging decorator.

Something like the following:

```
def exception_catcher(fn):
    try:
        fn()
    except Exception as e:
        log(e)
```

Then just use it around your code:

```
@exception_catcher
sadd('s', *array)
```

The comment and link to [Exceptions for the whole class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232373/exceptions-for-the-whole-class) suggested by @idanshmu will offer more detailed handling of different `Exceptions` per method.

Comment: hi Ewan,  it is not the same exception.   BTW, where can I find the whole list @xxxx python support ?

Comment: hi Ewan, it should be the same exception.  understand your suggestion now.  Thank you!