# How to create a Python decorator that can wrap either coroutine or function?

Tags: decorator, python-asyncio

I am trying to make a decorator to wrap either coroutines or functions.

The first thing I tried was a simple duplicate code in wrappers:

```py
def duration(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_ts = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        dur = time.time() - start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))
        return result

    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def async_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_ts = time.time()
        result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        dur = time.time() - start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))
        return result

    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        return async_wrapper
    else:
        return wrapper
```

This works, but i want to avoid duplication of code, as this is not much better than writing two separate decorators.

Then i tried to make a decorator using class:

```py
class SyncAsyncDuration:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_ts = None

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def sync_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.setup(func, args, kwargs)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.teardown(func, args, kwargs)
            return result

        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def async_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.setup(func, args, kwargs)
            result = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            self.teardown(func, args, kwargs)
            return result

        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            return async_wrapper
        else:
            return sync_wrapper

    def setup(self, func, args, kwargs):
        self.start_ts = time.time()

    def teardown(self, func, args, kwargs):
        dur = time.time() - self.start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))
```

That works in some cases very well for me, but in this solution i can't put a function in **with** or **try** statements.
Is there any way i can create a decorator without duplicating code?

Comment: Note that while *every* answer (so far) checks if the function is a coroutine, this will break in some cases, and the actually universal method is to synchronously call the function first, then check if the return value is an awaitable.

Comment: I wonder if there is a solution that still is a class and not a higher order function.

Comment: @DarkMath check out this gist https://gist.github.com/anatoly-kussul/f2d7444443399e51e2f83a76f112364d

Answer (score 20, accepted):

May be you can find better way to do it, but, for example, you can just move your wrapping logic to some context manager to prevent code duplication:

```
import asyncio
import functools
import time
from contextlib import contextmanager


def duration(func):
    @contextmanager
    def wrapping_logic():
        start_ts = time.time()
        yield
        dur = time.time() - start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            with wrapping_logic():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            async def tmp():
                with wrapping_logic():
                    return (await func(*args, **kwargs))
            return tmp()
    return wrapper
```

Comment: You can use `time.monotonic()` instead of `time.time()` to prevent side effect of a time update on the system.

Comment: This works for me with normal functions but does not with async coroutines.  `return tmp()` raises an exception.  I thought maybe changing to `return tmp` would work, and indeed that removes the exception, but then it never executes the decorated function.

Comment: @Ben can you provide an example of a code that doesn't work?

Comment: I figured out my error in the code from my last comment. I wasn't grabbing the event loop before calling the async method. I'm still having trouble with this using FastAPI. I can create a decorator for an async fastapi method. I can create a decorator for a normal fastapi function. But when I try to combine them in the way you've outlined, I get `ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]` Code: https://github.com/falkben/fastapi_experiments/blob/master/fastapi/flexible_fastapi_decorator.py

Comment: One important downside of this solution is that calling `aysncio.iscoroutinefunction()` on a coroutine wrapped with such decorator would always return `False`. As the `@coroutine` decorator is deprecated, the best approach is to declare two wrappers as OP did, and use the context manager to factorize what can be.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov shouldn't you be using `return await tmp()` instead of `return tmp()` ?

Comment: @y_159 no, you can't do it since the outer function `wrapper` is not async. You can only await inside async functions (defined with `async def`). But the solution in the answer should work as long as we wrap coroutine function: a regular coroutine function when called should return a coroutine object and that's what a decorated version will do as well - the wrapper upon call returns the coroutine object `tmp()`

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov with this i'm getting same error as @Ben commented. I tried to call the `tmp()` in an executor/using create_task but none of them seems to work. when i'm making wrapper itself as `async` then normal functions is not executing with this decorator.

Comment: @y_159 can you provide the full code?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov Its a big repo i'm working on, can't paste it here or in public. I'll try to reproduce the issue and ask it as a separate question, will paste the link here. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 6):

For me the accepted answer by @mikhail-gerasimov was not working w/ async FastAPI methods (though it did work with normal and coroutine functions outside of FastAPI). However, I found [this](https://gist.github.com/Integralist/77d73b2380e4645b564c28c53fae71fb#file-python-asyncio-timing-decorator-py) example on github that does work w/ fastapi methods.  Adapted (slightly) below:

```py
def duration(func):

    async def helper(func, *args, **kwargs):
        if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            print(f"this function is a coroutine: {func.__name__}")
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            print(f"not a coroutine: {func.__name__}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_ts = time.time()
        result = await helper(func, *args, **kwargs)
        dur = time.time() - start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))

        return result

    return wrapper
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the contextmanager, you can also do that:

```py
def duration(func):
    """ decorator that can take either coroutine or normal function """
    @contextmanager
    def wrapping_logic():
        start_ts = time.time()
        yield
        dur = time.time() - start_ts
        print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func.__name__, dur))

    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
            with wrapping_logic():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            with wrapping_logic():
                return (await func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

The difference between this and the accepted answer is not large. Mainly we just need to create an async wrapper and await the function if the function is a coroutine.

In my testing, this example code works in `try/except` blocks in your decorated function as well as `with` statements.

It's still not clear to me why the wrapper needs to be async for async FastAPI methods.

Comment: The big downside of this solution is that you have to always call wrapped functions with `await`. You can not use this decorator in sync code anymore, this is the solution i created based on accepted answer: https://gist.github.com/anatoly-kussul/f2d7444443399e51e2f83a76f112364d/ff1f94b1bd07741ce209cc61832f920adb49aedf
The idea is that you have to use two type of wrappers, sync and async, and choose which one to return based on input func. I hade this idea in original post, the thing i was missing is context manager to remove duplicated code

Comment: When you say does not work with "sync code anymore", what exactly do you mean?  For me, sync code was still working with this though I didn't try anything except toy excamples. It does get a bit complicated with the sync function being wrapped by an async wrapper. I do see the benefit to your solution. However, my sync code did run at least with those async wrappers.

Comment: I mean that when you apply your decorator to a sync function, you can no longer call this function in sync code, you have to use it with `await` syntax.
So if you want to make universal decorator to apply it in any place in the code without making it all run async (e.g. you have some parts running sync in threads) this solution will not work.
UPD: in short, your wrapper turns every wrapped function into a coroutine.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, thanks for the additional explanation. I think it was only working in FastAPI because FastAPI is fully async and spawns threads for anything sync and then awaits those threads. But I think this decorator would have put all sync code in the main event loop which would have been bad.  I feel like your gist is a bit better than the accepted answer.

Comment: The main problem with using your example with FastAPI is following: FastAPI can run both sync and async handlers, in your example, when you are wrapping sync handler with your decorator, it transforms this handler into a coroutine, and will be ran in a loop  instead of threadpool, as it does with sync handler. So if you have sync blocking code in your handler, and wrap it with your decorator, it will block entire loop when running it.

Answer (score 5):

In agreement with Anatoly, this solution puts together previous answers and makes sure the original type of func is preserved (if sync keeping decorated func sync, if async keeping it async):

```
import time
import asyncio
from contextlib import contextmanager
import functools

def decorate_sync_async(decorating_context, func):
    if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
        async def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            with decorating_context():
                return (await func(*args, **kwargs))
    else:
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            with decorating_context():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return functools.wraps(func)(decorated)

@contextmanager
def wrapping_logic(func_name):
    start_ts = time.time()
    yield
    dur = time.time() - start_ts
    print('{} took {:.2} seconds'.format(func_name, dur))


def duration(func):
    timing_context = lambda: wrapping_logic(func.__name__)
    return decorate_sync_async( timing_context, func )
```

`decorate_sync_async` can now be reused with any wrapping logic (contextmanager), to create a decorator that works for both sync and async functions.

To use it (and check it):

```
@duration
def sync_hello():
    print('sync_hello')

@duration
async def async_hello():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('async_hello')

async def main():
    print(f"is {sync_hello.__name__} async? "
        f"{asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(sync_hello)}") # False
    sync_hello()

    print(f"is {async_hello.__name__} async? "
        f"{asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(async_hello)}") # True
    await async_hello()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
sync_hello async? False
sync_hello
sync_hello took 0.0 seconds
is async_hello async? True
async_hello
async_hello took 0.1 seconds
```

Comment: How can I use your code with implementing more logic ? For example, I wanted to create to `retry(number_of_retry)` that can accept sync or async function. But In my case, I need to loop while retry > 0 and yielding in a contextmanager must me done once.