# Conditional Yield for Wrapping Functions and Coroutines

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, coroutine

Is there a canonical way of decorating a function and coroutine?

```
def timed(func):
    """
    A decorator for logging the execution time of each function decorated with it.

    :param func: function to be wrapped
    :return: a decorated function (in __debug__ mode) or the function is untouched.
    """
    if not __debug__:
        return func

    name = func.__name__
    logger = logging.getLogger("timer")
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    is_coro = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func)
    wrapper = asyncio.coroutine if is_coro else lambda f: f

    @functools.wraps(func)
    @wrapper
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            # if is_coro:
            #     yield from val
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug("{} failed in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            raise e
        else:
            logger.debug("{} ran in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            return val
    return wrapped
```

The commented out lines will, of course, change the `wrapped` function into a generator, regardless of whether or not `asyncio.coroutine` is used as a decorator.

Is there a better way of doing this other than separating it out into two distinct functions:

```
def timed(func):
    """
    A decorator for logging the execution time of each function decorated with it.

    :param func: function to be wrapped
    :return: a decorated function (in __debug__ mode) or the function is untouched.
    """
    if not __debug__:
        return func

    name = func.__name__
    logger = logging.getLogger("timer")
    logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    is_coro = asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug("{} failed in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            raise e
        else:
            logger.debug("{} ran in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            return val

    @functools.wraps(func)
    async def wrapped_async(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        try:
            val = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug("{} failed in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            raise e
        else:
            logger.debug("{} ran in {:.05}s".format(name, time.time() - start))
            return val

    return wrapped_async if is_coro else wrapped
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169998/567620

Comment: @ely awesome, thanks. Closing questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Python decorator that can wrap either coroutine or function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169998/how-to-create-a-python-decorator-that-can-wrap-either-coroutine-or-function)