# Decorator for all async, coroutine and sync functions?

Tags: python

I created the following decorator for both async/coroutine and sync functions.

```
def authorize(role):
    def decorator(f):

        @contextmanager
        def auth(): # Business logic shared by async and sync funtions
            if is_authorized(role): # role admin returns True, otherwise False
                yield
            else:
                print('ERROR')
                        
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
                with auth():
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                async def tmp():
                    with auth():
                        return (await f(*args, **kwargs))
                return tmp()
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

It works well if `is_authorized()` returns True.

```
@authorize(role='Readonly')
def test():
    print('TEST')

test()
```

However, it will raise exception when `is_authorized()` returns False. The decorated function shouldn't be called if it not authorized, it should return 501 HTTP error.

```
@authorize(role='Readonly')
def test():
    print('TEST')
```

```
ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "", line 13, in wrapper
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 115, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

Comment: why do you need contexmanager here? contextmanagers are useful when you need to release resources, or maybe to wrap the code and suppress exceptions, but not to replace the `if` statement

Comment: In the following question, the `contextmanager` is used for sharing the logic for the two cases, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169998/how-to-create-a-python-decorator-that-can-wrap-either-coroutine-or-function

Comment: Well, there is, but also, it's the different case there, and you need just if statement :-)

Answer (score 2):

The error raised because `contextmanager` must be the generator, it means it must always execute `yield` statement because `yield` separates the `__enter__` and `__exit__` parts of contextmanager. In your implementation it yields only if `is_autorized` returns `True`.

And actually you don't need the `contexmanager` here, you need simple `if` statement.

I'm passing `is_authorized` through arguments because it's useful for injecting alternative implementations for testing or other purposes.

```
import asyncio
import functools


def authorize(role, is_authorized):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if is_authorized(role):
                if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
                    async def tmp():
                        return (await f(*args, **kwargs))
                    return tmp()
                else:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
            elif asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
                # must return coro anyway
                async def tmp():
                    print("async unauthorized")
                    return None
                return tmp()
            else:
                print("sync unauthorized")
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator


def is_authorized(role):
    return role == "lucky"


@authorize("lucky", is_authorized)
async def func1():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return "coro finished"

@authorize("whatever", is_authorized)
async def func2():
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return "coro would not called"

@authorize("lucky", is_authorized)
def func3():
    return "sync func finished"

@authorize("whatever", is_authorized)
def func4():
    return "would not called"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(func1()))
    print(asyncio.run(func2()))
    print(func3())
    print(func4())
```

prints

```
coro finished

async unauthorized
None

sync func finished

sync unauthorized
None
```